# Why is my session attribute stale after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, session, servlets

What I'm trying to do is

1. When a button is clicked, make a request to a servlet to get the records from the database
2. Then set these records to the session
3. After this request is done, load the modal to show the records

And I have the following codes:

**JQUERY**

```
$("#currentItem").focus(loadPlantilla);
function loadPlantilla() {
    var code = $("#code").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: './profile/ViewPlantillaPicker?code=' + code,
        type: 'POST',
    }).done(function() {                    
        $('#modal').modal('show');
    });
}
```

**SERVLET**

```
int code = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("code"));

...

List<PlantillaView> plantilla = dao.read(...);

HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("plantilla", plantilla);
```

**MARKUP**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">

            ...    

            <div class="modal-body">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                    <thead> ... </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <c:forEach var="plantilla" items="${sessionScope.plantilla}">                                     
                            <tr>  
                                <td><c:out value="${plantilla.getItemCode()}"/></td>
                                <td><c:out value="${plantilla.getNewItemCode()}"/></td>
                                <td><c:out value="${plantilla.getPosition()}"/></td>
                                <td><c:out value="${plantilla.getStation()}"/></td>                                                                        
                                <td class="tools">                                    
                                    <form action="PickPlantilla" method="post" class="tool-options">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="itemCode" value="${plantilla.getItemCode()}">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Select">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-up"></span>                                     
                                        </button>
                                    </form>                                                        
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </c:forEach>  
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**PROBLEM**

After making the request, the modal is shown but it still contains the previous value of the session even though a new value is set. How do I fix this? I tried refreshing the page before showing the modal using `location.reload();` but apparently it's not the right solution. Please help?

*If there's a better way to do this (which is most probable) please let me know. Also I'm new to JQuery and AJAX so some explanations to your solution would be greatly appreciated.*

Comment: Because making an ajax request doesn't magically change the markup. You need to take the response and do something with it.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli: My servlet is just setting a new value to the session. It doesn't return some kind of response.

Comment: The same thing applies.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli, then what am I suppose to do?

Comment: Either refresh the page, so then the markup can regenerate. Or have the server send a response, process that response and update the markup appropriately.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli I tried refreshing the page before showing the modal by `location.reload();` but after the page refreshes, it doesn't load the modal anymore. In this case, I'm only left with sending a response. Is there a way to send `List<SomeObject>` back to the AJAX call?